PDFReader not opened with owner password - using Itextsharp PDFCopyFields.AddDocument
We recently changed PDFs to an encrypted\Secure PDF (no password needed to open in adobe reader) and now get the error: PDFReader not opened with owner password.

Using iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 3.4.3 with .Net 6.0 / c#

Error
 MemoryStream stream = new();
 PdfCopyFields copy = new(stream);
foreach (LetterTemplate t in sourceFiles)
{ 
    //This throws the error using an encrypted PDF.
    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(t.Data)); // t.Data is a byte array. 
}

I tried PdfReader.unethicalreading = true; and pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);
which I found suggested on older-looking posts but these properties are not available.
Is there a new property\method I can use which replaced unethicalreading?

PdfReader.AllowOpenWithFullPermissions = true;


